# Find out latency in a reliable way

Tags: networking, latency, exploit, anti-cheat

*Background:* I am developing a small game and use the player's latency to do [lag compensation](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/lag-compensation.html). The game is open sourced, so at the moment it is a very easy task to reverse engineer the system and delay ones response time to artificially increment ones reported delay, resulting in possibly unfair advantages.

---

My current strategy for latency retrieval is:

- Every fixed interval I send a message labeled as "ping" to a player. (This has nothing to do with ICMP)
- This ping message consists of a special "ping" opcode and a payload with a sequence number
- Once the client receives said message, he sends back one with a "pong" opcode and a payload with the same sequence number
- When the server receives the message labeled as "pong", it calculates how much time passed in between sending and receiving. This is the round trip time
- Our latency is the rtt / 2

---

*In pseudo code*

Server:

```
function now() {
    return current UTC time in millis
}

i = 0
function nextSequence() {
    return i++
}

sendingTimestamps = []
function onPingEvent() {
    id = nextSequence()
    sendingTimestamps[id] = now()
    sendPingMessage(id)
}

function onPongReceived(id) {
    received = now()
    sent = sendingTimestamps[id]
    rtt = received - sent
    latency = rtt / 2
}
```

---

Client:

```
function onPingReceived(id) {
    sendPongMessage(id)
}
```

As you can see, it's very easy for the client to just add a delay in his code to inflate his reported latency.

Is there a better way to get a clients latency in order to leave them less room for cheating?

Comment: The latency reported by ping is only for ICMP. I doubt you are using ICMP for your game, so the ICMP latency probably doesn't directly relate to the latency in the protocol that you are using. It's like measuring how fast you can go in traffic on one road, but trying to apply it to a different raod with different traffic conditions. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: You're right, but I am not using an ICMP ping. I send a TCP message over a websocket to the client who responds again on the same socket which is also used for the rest of the communication. Edited the question to mention that.

Comment: Then you shouldn't call it ping. Ping is an application created many years ago that uses ICMP echo and ICMP echo reply to determine if a host can be reached. You confuse things by naming it the same as something else.

Comment: @RonMaupin Good point. Would `delay` be a better name?

Comment: Well, you are trying to check latency, so maybe that. One problem is that you may have asymmetric routing, which can be common on the Internet, so simply taking the round trip time and dividing by two doesn't really reflect the latency of either leg. You can measure the latency of the round trip, but one direction could be twice as fast as the other direction.

Comment: @RonMaupin Makes sense. Do you know a way to account for this?

Comment: I stumbled across [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5132/8499) and answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer suggest either use ICMP which wouldn't work in this case or just measure the latency by hand, which we already do :)

Comment: No, the answer explains that you must have the clocks synchronized. It says you can use something other than ICMP. The point is that the devices must use the same NTP servers so that the clocks are closely synchronized, and you can get an accurate one-way latency.

Comment: I have never done anything related to NTP, so forgive me if I'm wrong. Wouldn't that require UDP? Note that I'm using WebSockets and I doubt that the overhead of making the protocols work together is worth the small boost in accuracy. Wouldn't it still be just as fake-able by the client?

Comment: NTP would be configured on the devices, not in your application. Each device can configure one or more NTP servers.

Comment: How would that work for an online game then? Is there a way to automatically force a clients browser to use a certain NTP with no possibility of them faking it?

Comment: Probably not. You would need to control the device. If this is TCP, you should be able to query TCP for the latency. I'm not sure of the specifics, but TCP does maintain this information in order to adjust the windows.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting, but what is the purpose of measuring latency at all? Lag compensation should rely on timestamps rather than measured packet delay which may change dynamically in wide ranges. Server starts emulating world on its side and sends command START to all clients. Clients initiate emulating world and count ticks from its creation. Whenever any event occurs on client side, client sends it with timestamp to server. Like "user pressed fire at tick #183".

Comment: ...server's emulation of game is far ahead due to packet transition time, but server can "go back in time" to handle user's order and resolve consequences.

Comment: @nnovich-OK Thank's for the info, looks like I understood the concept wrong then! How does one verify those timestamps though? Is there any way of blocking the client from pretending to have clicked something in the past?

Comment: AFAIU problem of verifying client input is generally unsolvable. Any algorithm implemented in client can be recreated to fake events/timestamps/packets. Closed code can be reversed, so it isn't an answer. Even world wide spread games like Counter-Strike or OverWatch have cheaters, despite they are developed by large companies, which, I bet, have separate department focused solely on game security. Some companies develop antivirus like modules, which check game file integrity or hash of parts of RAM snapshot, but it still can be passed.

Comment: The question is amount of efforts required to fake algorithm. The more efforts needed the less fakers will be. Trivial timestamp verifycation is the following: 1) if you receive event 2 in TCP stream after event 1, but its timestamp is before event 1, then it's faked 2) if timestamp is far behind servers time, then warn and kick player for enormous bad delay. If it is real player, the game anyway is unplayable for him, otherwise you kicked hacker. CS servers do this if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @nnovich-OK That's what I feared. If you post the info about how I understood lag compensation wrong, how player input cannot be really verified and about how to trivially check for fake inputs, I will upvote and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer below is a summary of topics discussed in comments to have them all in one place.

### Lag compensation should rely on precise time stamp of event rather than average packet delay

Transition time may drastically vary even for two successive packets. Suggested approach with measuring average latency and assuming, that each received packet was sent "latency" ms ago for lag compensation is way too inaccurate. The following scheme should be applied instead:

Server starts emulating world on its side and sends command START to all clients. Clients initiate emulating world and count ticks from its creation. Whenever any event occurs on client side, client sends it with timestamp to server. Like "user pressed fire at tick #183". Server's emulation of game is far ahead due to packet transition time, but server can "go back in time" to handle user's order and resolve consequences.

### Time stamps and events still can be faked

AFAIU problem of verifying client input is generally unsolvable. Any algorithm implemented in client can be recreated to fake events/timestamps/packets. Closed code can be reversed, so it is not an answer. Even world wide spread games like Counter-Strike or OverWatch have cheaters, despite they are developed by large companies, which, I bet, have separate department focused solely on game security. Some companies develop antivirus like modules, which check game file integrity or hash of parts of RAM snapshot, but it still can be bypassed.

The question is amount of efforts required to fake algorithm. The more efforts needed the less fakers will be. Trivial timestamp verifycation is the following:

1. If you receive event#2 in TCP stream after event#1, but its time stamp is before event#1, then it's faked.
2. If time stamp is far behind server's time, then warn and kick player for enormously bad delay. If it's a real player, the game anyway is unplayable for him, otherwise you kicked hacker. CS servers do this if I'm not mistaken.